# C programming: IP header ID is negative

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, printf

I have following code:

```
struct ip_header {
        unsigned char ip_hl:4;
        unsigned char ip_ver:4;
        unsigned char ip_dscp:6;
        unsigned char ip_ecn:2;
        short ip_len;
        short ip_id;
...
};
...

const struct ip_header * ip_hdr = (const struct ip_header *)(buffer + ETHERNET_HEADER_SIZE);

...

printf("IP ID: %d", ip_hdr->ip_id);
```

IP ID I get is negative for most of the packets. Can you guys see a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%d prints a signed integer (so here it converts your unsigned int into a signed int). Use %u for unsigned integers.

Comment: Since ip_id is a short, I believe %hu is a better choice.

Comment: I should not have used short for IP ID in the frst place, thanks for the hint. Now when I use %u I get ID as 1600 for all packets. Do you think it is normal? Shouldn't it be different for each packet?